# PHP login code, clean up

Tags: php, authentication

I would like to clean up my login script and help make it safe for my database. I am a basic coder and learned what I have from tutorials, so I guess my script needs some protections, any suggestions?

```
<?php

session_start();

$email = strtolower( trim($_POST['email']));
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($email&&$pass){

require_once("dbconnect.php");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$email'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows!=0){   
//code to login
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dbusername = $row['username'];        //USERNAME IS NAME OF COLUMN IN DB
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        $activated = $row['activated'];

        if ($activated=='0')
            die("Your account has not been activated.(Remember to check in your email spam folder)");
    }

    //check to see if they match
    if ($email==$dbusername&&md5($pass)==$dbpassword){
        //echo "You have succesfully logged-in! <a href='start.php'>Click</a> here to enter." ;
        $_SESSION['username']=$email;
        header( 'Location: http://website' ) ;
    }
    else{
        echo "The password you entered is incorrect";   
    }
}
else
    die("Sorry, the email you have entered is incorrect");

}

else
    die("Please enter your email and password");


?>
```

Comment: This type of code review question is better suited to... [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: md5 is not a secure hashing algorithm.  I suggest PHP's `crypt` function for password hashing.  It makes the whole process much easier than other methods.

Comment: @G-Nugget: I cannot agree that `crypt()` is *easier* (as you said) than `md5()`

Comment: Anyway, use prepared statements PDO instead of `mysql_` to protect against SQL injection and to just generally make things more convenient and neater; use bcrypt or scrypt for hashing passwords; put spaces around your operators.

Comment: @minitech: you only left "wash your hands before you start programming" ;-)

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava: deprec**a**ted, no *i* there

Comment: @minitech: they are just typo and slang, but `depreciated` is what makes me sad (even though I'm terrible English speaker myself) each time I see it

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava: they **ARE NOT** vulnerable

Comment: The basic code looks OK.  Just at random: Formatting will help.  For example, indenting for the first "if" as well as for the others.  For security, adding protection against SQL injection would be good too.  There seems to be a bug when the supplied password is the empty string: it evaluates to false, and you will respond as if the user failed to supply it.

Comment: @zerkms I can't argue that `crypt()` is easier to use than `md5 ()` as it is used here, but this implementation is not secure.  `crypt()` puts the hash, salt, difficulty, and algorithm in one string, allowing a password to be verified in one easy line instead of having to build the whole process by getting the hash and salt separately and it allows different algorithms and difficulties to be used simultaneously with the same code.

Comment: PDO seems to be a lot of info, can anyone clarify how they would use it in this code instead of mysql_ because that is pretty much the only database coding i know

Comment: @G-Nugget: I don't argue it's more secure, but you said it's easier to use. `md5('pass')` - show the same with `crypt()` and let's compare which is easier to write

Comment: @zerkms So I should have said that it's easier than other _secure_ methods, but crypt can be used like `crypt('pass')`, although with much weaker security.

Comment: ALSO should i add mysql_real_escape_string() and if so where?

Answer (score 2):

Look, I rewrote it for you! This uses PDO and prepared statements, which patches the SQL injection vulnerability in the most elegant way possible (i.e. not `mysql_real_escape_string`), and also uses bcrypt for hashing passwords, which is infinitely better than one MD5 with no salt.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';

    $email = strtolower(trim($_POST['email']));
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :email LIMIT 1');
    $query->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    $row = $query->fetch();

    if($row) {
        if(!$row->activated) {
            die('Your account has not been activated. (Remember to check in your e-mail spam folder!)');
        }

        if($row->username === $email && crypt($password, $row->password) === $row->password) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
            header('Location: http://website'); # If this isn't a relative URL, try using one.
            exit();
        }
    }

    die('Invalid e-mail and/or password. Please try again.');
}
?>
```

You'll need to make a couple changes to your database, to your registration code, and to your database connection code, however.

Comment: this looks great, can anyone second that this is the code to use?

Comment: wait what changes to database must i make?

Comment: @user1664386: Well, you'll need to change the size of the `password` field to 61 to accommodate the different hashing algorithm. And that's pretty much it.

Comment: thanks minitech ill try out code

Comment: dont hate me man but i posted my registration page also, i just need as much help as i can get

Comment: Tiny note: `isset` accepts N parameters: `isset($a, $b)` and it's eq to `isset($a) && isset($b)`

Comment: Also `crypt($password, $row->password) === $row->password` doesn't look correct

Comment: @zerkms: It is. That is how bcrypt works. And thanks for the `isset` tip! I never knew that.

Comment: @minitech: are you sure the second parameter isn't salt there?

Comment: @zerkms: It is, but the salt is included in the hash, and the actual hash is ignored when it's passed as a salt.

Comment: @minitech: oh, it really is. I owe you - `isset` trick is not that important like this knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would fix the SQL injection vulnerability by changing:

```
$email = strtolower( trim($_POST['email']));
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($email&&$pass){

    require_once("dbconnect.php");
```

to

```
require_once("dbconnect.php");

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower( trim($_POST['email'])));
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($email&&$pass){
```

The next thing you could do is prevent against "session hijacking" by changing

```
if ($email==$dbusername&&md5($pass)==$dbpassword){
    //echo "You have succesfully logged-in! <a href='start.php'>Click</a> here to enter." ;
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;
```

to

```
if ($email==$dbusername&&md5($pass)==$dbpassword){
    //echo "You have succesfully logged-in! <a href='start.php'>Click</a> here to enter." ;
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['username']=$email;
```

I am not sure where this login script is being used (internally or externally) but if its used externally, you could add the users ip address as a session variable and check that everytime a user returns. I would also use the crypt() function instead of md5() because md5() is NOT recommended for hashing passwords (this might depend on how many users you have and if you want to reset everyones password). I use the [PHPass class](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
Besides security, you could be using MySQLi (aka MySQL improved) instead of the original MySQL code because it is being deprecated. But changing to MySQLi depends on if your PHP supports MySQLi.

Comment: The password should not be escaped since it is getting hashed.  technically you could escape it as long as you make sure it's always escaped, but it's easier to leave it unescaped everywhere since it never really goes to the database.